Find Different ID's That Belongs to Another Same ID



CUST ID
ORDER ID




12455
4070


12454
4070


12454
4077


12455
4077


12454
2659


12455
1928


12454
2012


12453
1354



I have a table that holds both customer id and order id. I need to find different customer id's with the same order id which the output should look like below. In this case 12455 and 12454 matches on same order id 4070, 4077.
What i need is a query like this if i select
select * from table where cust_id in (12455, 12454) ... query continues

the output should like below because 4070 and 4077 are common in given cust id's



ORDER ID




4070


4077



if i select for select * from table where cust_id in (12454,12455,12453) ... query continues output should be empty.

To confirm - the output is order_ids with more than one cust_id ?

No, i need to find order ids that matches 12454 and 12455.  For example if there was an cust id with 12453 and no order id that matches with 12454, 12455  and if I wanted to select 12454 , 12455 and 12453 the output sholud be empty. The case I showed to you, you can think that I selected 12454 and 12455.

can you post your code what you have tried ?

why output should be empty in the second query ?

Why does 1928, 2659 and 2012 not appear? Is the logic perhaps: return OrderID where that OrderID is present for all the specified CustID?

@Charlieface because those order numbers are not shared between both users

Could you tag the RDBMS you are using

Your logic is not completely clear, but it seems to be a classic Relational Division Without Remainder problem
WITH IdsToSearch AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (12455), (12454) ) v(ID)
)
SELECT
  t.ORDERID
FROM YourTable t
JOIN IdsToSearch i ON i.ID = t.cust_id
GROUP BY
  t.ORDERID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IdsToSearch);


If you have a collection type:
CREATE TYPE number_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

Then you can pass a list of customer IDs as a bind variable:
SELECT order_id
FROM   table_name
WHERE  cust_id MEMBER OF :customer_id_list
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) = CARDINALITY(:customer_id_list)

Which for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (CUST_ID, ORDER_ID) AS
SELECT 12455, 4070 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12454, 4070 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12454, 4077 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12455, 4077 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12454, 2659 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12455, 1928 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12454, 2012 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12453, 1354 FROM DUAL;

If :customer_id_list is number_list(12455, 12454) then the output is:



ORDER_ID




4070


4077



and if :customer_id_list is number_list(12455, 12454, 12453) then no rows are output.
fiddle

Good answer. Note that TVPs or collection/list types are DBMS specific, not all support it. Assuming CUST_ID, ORDER_ID is a unique set then COUNT(DISTINCT CUST_ID) could be COUNT(*).

@Charlieface The OP edited the question to tag it with Oracle.

Yeah true, was just pointing out that it differs by DBMS, if someone wants to reuse this answer.

Another option would be using a subquery to get the total number of search custId used
SELECT orderId
FROM myTable
WHERE custId IN (12455, 12454)
GROUP BY orderId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT custId) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT custId)
    FROM myTable
    WHERE custId IN (12455, 12454)
);

See example

This should work
select distinct cust_id 
from table 
where cust_id not in (<list of customer ids>)
and order_id in (
    select oder_id 
    from table 
    where cust_id in (<list of customer ids>))


@Charlieface's answer is great. Here is an alternative solution that also requires passing the total number of customers :
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM mytable 
WHERE CUST_ID in (12454, 12455, 12453)
GROUP BY ORDER_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- 3 is the total number of customers 

Demo here

You search orders wit more than 1 customer.
Count number of customers for order and take those, where count>1.
See example
select order_id
  , min(cust_id) cust_id1
  , max(cust_id) cust_id2
  ,count(*) cnt
from data
group by order_id
having count(*)>1
  and min(cust_id)<>max(cust_id)




order_id
cust_id1
cust_id2
cnt




4070
12454
12455
2


4077
12454
12455
2



Demo example
Upd1. Check case when pair (cust_id, order_id) has duplicates.

This answer is not correct because you do not take in consideration the shared part. See https://dbfiddle.uk/H_qnCHyp where there is nothing shared between 12454 and 12455

ErgestBasha, your comment is right. I will add check for.
